# Cells do not show up in my tableview

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, sorting, swift2

I am new to swift / Xcode. I am stuck, i have created a struct with a sectionName, Sectionobject, and section image. I believe that my code is correct, but when i run the simulator it will not populate the tableview with the cells that i have created. The cell type is Basic, and the identifier is cell.

There are no errors besides a yellow triangle that says "Initialization of immutable value 'objectarray' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it" around the object array variable

When i run this code, it doesn't call any of the tableview func 's .

i have removed most of the content in the ObjectArray ,and replaced them with "Xxxxx" to make it easier.

i must be missing something , Here is the code :

```
class "classname" : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,     UITableViewDataSource {

struct Objects {
    var sectionName : String!
    var sectionObjects : [String]!
    var sectionImage : [UIImage]!
    }

var objectArray = [Objects]()

@IBOutlet weak var "myname"TableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  let objectarray = [Objects(sectionName: "Drinks", sectionObjects: ["xxxxxx"], sectionImage:  [UIImage(named: "coollime.jpg")!,
   ]),

  Objects(sectionName: "Fresh Brewed Coffee Drinks", sectionObjects: ["Blonde Roast",
  "Caffè Misto",
  "xxxxx"], sectionImage: [UIImage(named: "br.jpg")!,
  UIImage(named: "cf.jpg")!,
  UIImage(named: "scbcm.jpg")!]),

  Objects(sectionName: "Espresso Beverages", sectionObjects: ["Caffè Americano",
  "Caffè Latte",
  "xxxxxxx", sectionImage: [UIImage(named: "ca1.jpg")!,
  "xxxxxxx"
  ]
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
  cell.textLabel?.text = self.objectArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row] 
  let imageName = objectArray[indexPath.section].sectionImage[indexPath.row] 
  cell.imageView!.image = imageName    
  return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
  return objectArray[section].sectionObjects.count
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
  return objectArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
  return objectArray[section].sectionName
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
  super.didReceiveMemoryWarning() }
}
```

Comment: The warning you're getting is because you are creating a new local 'objectArray' variable inside `viewDidLoad` instead of initialising your member variable 'objectArray'.  Simply remove the word `let' and it should work.

Comment: Did you set the delegate and the data source to your view controller?

Comment: that was it sgib , thank you so much!